# Can dplyr package be used for conditional mutating?

Tags: r, if-statement, case-when, dplyr

Can the mutate be used when the mutation is conditional (depending on the values of certain column values)?

This example helps showing what I mean.

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5, 1), b = c(1, 3, 4, 
2, 6, 7, 2, 6), c = c(6, 3, 6, 5, 3, 6, 5, 3), d = c(6, 2, 4, 
5, 3, 7, 2, 6), e = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 3), f = c(2, 3, 4, 
2, 2, 7, 5, 2)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")

  a b c d e f
1 1 1 6 6 1 2
2 3 3 3 2 2 3
3 4 4 6 4 4 4
4 6 2 5 5 5 2
5 3 6 3 3 6 2
6 2 7 6 7 7 7
7 5 2 5 2 6 5
8 1 6 3 6 3 2
```

I was hoping to find a solution to my problem using the dplyr package (and yes I know this not code that should work, but I guess it makes the purpose clear) for creating a new column g:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df <- mutate(df,
         if (a == 2 | a == 5 | a == 7 | (a == 1 & b == 4)){g = 2},
         if (a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 4 | a == 3 |  c == 4) {g = 3})
```

The result of the code I am looking for should have this result in this particular example:

```
  a b c d e f  g
1 1 1 6 6 1 2  3
2 3 3 3 2 2 3  3
3 4 4 6 4 4 4  3
4 6 2 5 5 5 2 NA
5 3 6 3 3 6 2 NA
6 2 7 6 7 7 7  2
7 5 2 5 2 6 5  2
8 1 6 3 6 3 2  3
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this in dplyr? This data frame is just an example, the data frames I am dealing with are much larger. Because of its speed I tried to use dplyr, but perhaps there are other, better ways to handle this problem?

Comment: Yes but `dplyr::case_when()` is much clearer than an `ifelse`,

Comment: See https://bookdown.org/ansellbr/WEHI_tidyR_course_book/manipulating-data-with-dplyr.html#case_when-helper for more information

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Use `ifelse`

```
df %>%
  mutate(g = ifelse(a == 2 | a == 5 | a == 7 | (a == 1 & b == 4), 2,
               ifelse(a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 4 | a == 3 |  c == 4, 3, NA)))
```

**Added - if_else:** Note that in dplyr 0.5 there is an `if_else` function defined so an alternative would be to replace `ifelse` with `if_else`; however, note that since `if_else` is stricter than `ifelse` (both legs of the condition must have the same type) so the `NA` in that case would have to be replaced with `NA_real_` .

```
df %>%
  mutate(g = if_else(a == 2 | a == 5 | a == 7 | (a == 1 & b == 4), 2,
               if_else(a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 4 | a == 3 |  c == 4, 3, NA_real_)))
```

**Added - case_when** Since this question was posted dplyr has added `case_when` so another alternative would be:

```
df %>% mutate(g = case_when(a == 2 | a == 5 | a == 7 | (a == 1 & b == 4) ~ 2,
                            a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 4 | a == 3 |  c == 4 ~ 3,
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

**Added - arithmetic/na_if**  If the values are numeric and the conditions (except for the default value of NA at the end) are mutually exclusive, as is the case in the question, then we can use an arithmetic expression such that each term is multiplied by the desired result using `na_if` at the end to replace 0 with NA.

```
df %>%
  mutate(g = 2 * (a == 2 | a == 5 | a == 7 | (a == 1 & b == 4)) +
             3 * (a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 4 | a == 3 |  c == 4),
         g = na_if(g, 0))
```

Comment: What is the logic if instead of `NA`, I want the rows that don't meet the conditions to just stay the same?

Comment: `mutate(g = ifelse(condition1, 2, ifelse(condition2, 3, g))`

Comment: case_when is sooooo beautiful, and it took me soooo long to figure out that it was actually there.
I think this should be in the simplest dplyr tutorials, it is very common to have the need for calculating stuff for subsets of the data, but still wanting to keep the data complete.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: From the discussion above and the help files, I understand the difference between `if_else()` and `ifelse()`. Can you use `ifelse()` with the `mutate` function correctly? Is there any recommendation to use `dplyr::if_else()` over `base:ifelse()` -- i.e. using the stricter `if_else()` may avoid unnecessary problems downstream?

Comment: You can use either one. It's mostly a matter of whether you prefer strictness or flexibility.

Answer (score 63):

Since you ask for other better ways to handle the problem, here's another way using `data.table`:

```r
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c == 4, g := 3L]
df[a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4), g := 2L]
```

Note the order of conditional statements is reversed to get `g` correctly. There's no copy of `g` made, even during the second assignment - it's replaced *in-place*.

On larger data this would have better performance than using *nested* `if-else`, as [it can evaluate both 'yes' and 'no' cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/559784), and nesting can get harder to read/maintain IMHO.

---

Here's a benchmark on relatively bigger data:

```r
# NB: benchmark timings are as of R 3.1.0, data.table v1.9.2
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)
DT <- setDT(lapply(1:6, function(x) sample(7, 1e7, TRUE)))
setnames(DT, letters[1:6])
# > dim(DT) 
# [1] 10000000        6
DF <- as.data.frame(DT)

DT_fun <- function(DT) {
    DT[(a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c == 4), g := 3L]
    DT[a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4), g := 2L]
}
DPLYR_fun <- function(DF) {
    mutate(DF, g = ifelse(a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4), 2L, 
           ifelse(a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c==4, 3L, NA_integer_)))
}

BASE_fun <- function(DF) { # R v3.1.0
    transform(DF, g = ifelse(a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4), 2L, 
              ifelse(a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c==4, 3L, NA_integer_)))
}

system.time(ans1 <- DT_fun(DT))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.659   0.420   3.107 

system.time(ans2 <- DPLYR_fun(DF))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 11.822   1.075  12.976 

system.time(ans3 <- BASE_fun(DF))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 11.676   1.530  13.319 

identical(as.data.frame(ans1), as.data.frame(ans2))
# [1] TRUE

identical(as.data.frame(ans1), as.data.frame(ans3))
# [1] TRUE
```

Not sure if this is an alternative you'd asked for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Nice piece of code! The answer of G. Grotendieck works and is short so i picked that one as the answer to my question, but I thank you for your solution. I sure will try it this way as well.

Comment: Since `DT_fun` is modifying its input inplace, the benchmark might not be quite fair - in addition to not receiving the same input from the 2nd iteration forward (which might affect timing since `DT$g` is already allocated?), the result also propagates back to `ans1` and therefore might (if R's optimizer deems it necessary? Not sure on this...) avoid *another* copy that `DPLYR_fun` and `BASE_fun` need to make?

Comment: Just to be clear though, I think this `data.table` solution is great, and I use `data.table` wherever I really need speed for operations on tables & I don't want to go all the way to C++.  It does require being really careful about modifications in place, though!

Comment: I'm trying to get used to more tidyverse stuff from data.table, and this is one of those examples of a pretty common use-case that data.table is both easier to read and more efficient. My main reason for wanting to develop more tidyverse in my vocabulary is readability for myself and others, but in this case it seems like data.table wins.

Answer (score 43):

dplyr now has a function `case_when` that offers a vectorised if. The syntax is a little strange compared to `mosaic:::derivedFactor` as you cannot access variables in the standard dplyr way, and need to declare the mode of NA, but it is considerably faster than `mosaic:::derivedFactor`.

```
df %>%
mutate(g = case_when(a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4) ~ 2L, 
                     a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c == 4 ~ 3L, 
                     TRUE~as.integer(NA)))
```

**EDIT:** If you're using `dplyr::case_when()` from before version 0.7.0 of the package, then you need to precede variable names with '`.$`' (e.g. write `.$a == 1` inside `case_when`).

**Benchmark**:
For the benchmark (reusing functions from Arun 's post) and reducing sample size:

```
require(data.table) 
require(mosaic) 
require(dplyr)
require(microbenchmark)

set.seed(42) # To recreate the dataframe
DT <- setDT(lapply(1:6, function(x) sample(7, 10000, TRUE)))
setnames(DT, letters[1:6])
DF <- as.data.frame(DT)

DPLYR_case_when <- function(DF) {
  DF %>%
  mutate(g = case_when(a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4) ~ 2L, 
                       a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c==4 ~ 3L, 
                       TRUE~as.integer(NA)))
}

DT_fun <- function(DT) {
  DT[(a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c == 4), g := 3L]
  DT[a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4), g := 2L]
}

DPLYR_fun <- function(DF) {
  mutate(DF, g = ifelse(a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4), 2L, 
                    ifelse(a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c==4, 3L, NA_integer_)))
}

mosa_fun <- function(DF) {
  mutate(DF, g = derivedFactor(
    "2" = (a == 2 | a == 5 | a == 7 | (a == 1 & b == 4)),
    "3" = (a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 4 | a == 3 |  c == 4),
    .method = "first",
    .default = NA
  ))
}

perf_results <- microbenchmark(
  dt_fun <- DT_fun(copy(DT)),
  dplyr_ifelse <- DPLYR_fun(copy(DF)),
  dplyr_case_when <- DPLYR_case_when(copy(DF)),
  mosa <- mosa_fun(copy(DF)),
  times = 100L
)
```

This gives:

```
print(perf_results)
Unit: milliseconds
           expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
         dt_fun   1.391402    1.560751   1.658337   1.651201   1.716851   2.383801   100
   dplyr_ifelse   1.172601    1.230351   1.331538   1.294851   1.390351   1.995701   100
dplyr_case_when   1.648201    1.768002   1.860968   1.844101   1.958801   2.207001   100
           mosa 255.591301  281.158350 291.391586 286.549802 292.101601 545.880702   100
```

Comment: `case_when` could also be written as: `df %>%
mutate(g = with(., case_when(a %in% c(2,5,7) | (a==1 & b==4) ~ 2L, 
                   a %in% c(0,1,3,4) | c==4 ~ 3L, 
                   TRUE ~ NA_integer_)))`

Comment: Is this benchmark in microseconds/milliseconds/days, what? This benchmark is meaningless without the measurement unit provided. Also, bench-marking on a data set smaller than 1e6 is meaningless too as it doesn't scale.

Comment: Pls modify your answer, you don't need the `.$` anymore in the new version of dplyr

Comment: @Matifou whats the difference between `DT[, col1 := case_when(col2 > value ~ TRUE)]` and `DT[col2 > value, col1 := TRUE]`?

Answer (score 14):

The `derivedFactor` function from `mosaic` package seems to be designed to handle this.  Using this example, it would look like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mosaic)
df <- mutate(df, g = derivedFactor(
     "2" = (a == 2 | a == 5 | a == 7 | (a == 1 & b == 4)),
     "3" = (a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 4 | a == 3 |  c == 4),
     .method = "first",
     .default = NA
     ))
```

(If you want the result to be numeric instead of a factor, you can wrap `derivedFactor` in an `as.numeric` call.)

`derivedFactor` can be used for an arbitrary number of conditionals, too.

Comment: @hadley should make this the default syntax for dplyr. Needing nested "ifelse" statements is the single worst part of the package, which is mainly the case because the other functions are so good

Comment: You can also prevent the result from being a factor using the `.asFactor = F` option or by using the (similar) `derivedVariable` function in the same package.

Comment: It looks like `recode` from dplyr 0.5 will do this.  I haven't investigated it yet though.  See https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/

Answer (score 14):

`case_when` is now a pretty clean implementation of the SQL-style case when:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5, 1), b = c(1, 3, 4, 
2, 6, 7, 2, 6), c = c(6, 3, 6, 5, 3, 6, 5, 3), d = c(6, 2, 4, 
5, 3, 7, 2, 6), e = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 3), f = c(2, 3, 4, 
2, 2, 7, 5, 2)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame") -> df


df %>% 
    mutate( g = case_when(
                a == 2 | a == 5 | a == 7 | (a == 1 & b == 4 )     ~   2,
                a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 4 |  a == 3 | c == 4       ~   3
))
```

Using dplyr 0.7.4

The manual: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html