# Conditional and/or nested ifelse mutate logic with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that is arranged like this:

```
ID   A   B  C   D   Win  Loss
001  NA  3  NA  NA  6    NA  
002  NA  NA NA  NA  NA   17
003  1   5  12  18  NA   22
004  NA  7  9   NA  31   NA
005  8   2  NA  NA  NA   14
006  2   6  12  19  25   NA
007  NA  NA NA  NA  6    NA
```

In this dataset, IDs are supposed to move through each stage (A, B, C, D) chronologically and hit either Win/Loss at the end (ID 003 and 006)

Sometimes, however, IDs move backwards (ID 005), others skip stages (ID 001 and 004) and some go directly to Win/Loss (ID 002 and 007).

I would like to call these out with dplyr mutate logic. Output:

```
ID   A   B  C   D   Win  Loss  Backwards Skip  Just W/L
001  NA  3  NA  NA  6    NA    F         T     F
002  NA  NA NA  NA  NA   17    F         T     T
003  1   5  12  18  NA   22    F         F     F
004  NA  7  9   NA  31   NA    F         T     F
005  8   2  NA  NA  NA   14    T         T     F
006  2   6  12  19  25   NA    F         F     F
007  NA  NA NA  NA  6    NA    F         T     T
```

I know that I should be using logic similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating), but I I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Bonus points if you can also tell me how to count the time/days elapsed between each stage even if it skips a couple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done using `base R`.  Select the columns of interest `df[LETTERS[1:4]]`, create a logical matrix of presence/absence of "NAs" (`is.na(df[...)`).  Negate it (`!`) so that non-NA elements become "TRUE", get the row wise sum `rowSums` and negate it `!` so the rows with `0` non-NA values will become TRUE, and that would be the case with just a win or loss.  For the "backwards", we can use a loop method (`apply(`) for rows (`MARGIN=1`), check whether the difference of non-NA elements (`diff(na.omit(x))`) have any negative number (`any(....)<0`).  If there is one, it indicates, IDs moved backwards.  The "Skip" is also similar to "JustWL" where we get the logical matrix (`is.na(..)`), sum by row (`rowSums`) and double negate (`!!`).  If there is at least one "NA", this will be TRUE.

```
JustWL <- !rowSums(!is.na(df[LETTERS[1:4]]))
Backwards <- apply(df[LETTERS[1:4]], 1, function(x) any(diff(na.omit(x))<0))
Skip <- !!rowSums(is.na(df[LETTERS[1:4]]))

df1 <- data.frame(df, JustWL, Backwards, Skip)
df1
#   ID  A  B  C  D Win Loss JustWL Backwards  Skip
# 1  1 NA  3 NA NA   6   NA  FALSE     FALSE  TRUE
# 2  2 NA NA NA NA  NA   17   TRUE     FALSE  TRUE 
# 3  3  1  5 12 18  NA   22  FALSE     FALSE FALSE
# 4  4 NA  7  9 NA  31   NA  FALSE     FALSE  TRUE
# 5  5  8  2 NA NA  NA   14  FALSE      TRUE  TRUE
# 6  6  2  6 12 19  25   NA  FALSE     FALSE FALSE
# 7  7 NA NA NA NA   6   NA   TRUE     FALSE  TRUE
```

Or using the same code in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    mutate(JustWL=!rowSums(!is.na(.[LETTERS[1:4]])), 
           Skip=!!rowSums(is.na(.[LETTERS[1:4]]))) %>%
           rowwise() %>% 
           do(data.frame(., Backwards= 
               any(diff(na.omit(unlist(.[LETTERS[1:4]])))<0)))
```

Comment: could you explain how the backwards any(diff() function and the skip !! command works?