# mutate new column that matches to defined strings

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, dplyr, grepl

I would like to `mutate` one of the columns of data frame depending on the certain conditions matched. I have looked the around but couldn't find some neat solution so far on this. [use-mutate-to-create-new-column-label-with-conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277717/use-mutate-to-create-new-column-label-with-conditions)

So here is the simple data frame that I used

```
gr = rep(seq(1,2),each=3)
clas=c("A_1","A_2","A_3","A_4","A_5","A_6")

df <- data.frame(gr,clas)

> df
  gr clas
1  1  A_1
2  1  A_2
3  1  A_3
4  2  A_4
5  2  A_5
6  2  A_6
```

I would like to chance A_4, A_5 and A_6 with B_1, B_2 and B_3

So I tried

```
match <- paste('_',seq(4,6),sep='')
 df%>%
  mutate(clas=ifelse(clas %in% match,paste('B',seq(1,3),sep='_'),clas))

       gr clas
    1  1    1
    2  1    2
    3  1    3
    4  2    4
    5  2    5
    6  2    6
```

and 2nd try with `grepl`

```
df%>%
mutate(clas=ifelse(clas==grepl(paste(match,collapse='|'),clas),paste('B',seq(1,3),sep='_'),clas))

   gr clas
1  1    1
2  1    2
3  1    3
4  2    4
5  2    5
6  2    6
```

Which is A's also gone :) The expected result is;

```
   gr clas
1  1  A_1
2  1  A_2
3  1  A_3
4  2  B_1
5  2  B_2
6  2  B_3
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I realized that it is easier to do if there are LETTERS in the data `clas` column. But if we have data like this and no `gr` column how do we that ??

```
    clas
1   CD_1
2  X.2_2
3  K$2_3
4 12k3_4
5   .A_5
6   xy_6
```

The expected output is

```
    clas
1   CD_1
2  X.2_2
3  K$2_3
4 12kB_4
5   .B_5
6   xB_6
```

I guess I was looking for solution like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `dplyr` solution:

```
df%>%group_by(gr)%>%dplyr::mutate(clas=paste0(toupper(letters[gr]),"_",row_number()))
#you can change toupper(letters[gr]) to LETTERS[gr]

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   gr [2]
     gr  clas
  <int> <chr>
1     1   A_1
2     1   A_2
3     1   A_3
4     2   B_1
5     2   B_2
6     2   B_3
```

Comment: May as well use `LETTERS` rather than `toupper(letters)`.

Comment: @Wen Hi Wen thanks for the answer. However, I just put letters in clas not in purpose the real solution I look for is in the EDIT part. Could you check OP's EDIT part. I guess your solution not working on that ?

Comment: @Wen Sorry I edited again the expected output. What I am looking is just change strings before the `_` to B and keep rest of it.

Comment: @Alexander   Seems like you do not need `dplyr` try this ?`paste0(str_sub(str_split_fixed(df$clas,"_",2)[1],1,-2),LETTERS[df$gr],'_',str_split_fixed(df$clas,"_",2)[,2])`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution that relies on `df$gr`:

```
paste(LETTERS[df$gr], ave(df$gr, df$gr, FUN=seq_along), sep="_")
[1] "A_1" "A_2" "A_3" "B_1" "B_2" "B_3
```

`LETTERS` are the Latin capital letters, `LETTERS[1]` is "A". So "A" and "B" are pasted to the results of the running count constructed by `seq_along` which is reset by group using `ave`. These two are pasted together with "_" as the separator.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to use base R: specifically just to solve this problem:

First ensure your vector is in character form. I called the table above `B`

```
  B[,1]=as.character(B[,1])
  B[4:6,1]=sapply(B$clas[4:6],function(i) {substr(i,nchar(i)-2,nchar(i)-2)<-"B";i})
  B
     clas
 1   CD_1
 2  X.2_2
 3  K$2_3
 4 12kB_4
 5   .B_5
 6   xB_6
```