# Make Score Sentiment to words in dataframe R

Tags: r

[image]

So i already have the score for my sentiment analysis, How to make the score to a words like

1. more than 5 is very positive
2. 1 to 5 is positive
3. 0 is neutral
4. -1 to -5 is very negative
5. less than 0 is negative

something like that and a nice ggplot will be very good...

i am now filling my negative and positive words, language i use is Indonesia

Comment: Try nested `ifelse()`

Comment: See `cut()` or `dplyr`'s `case_when()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(mosaic)
emotion <- mutate(analysis, score = derivedFactor(
  "Netral" = (score == 0),
  "Sangat Positif" = (score > 5), 
  "Positif" = (score == 1 | score == 2 | score == 3 | score == 4 ),
  "Sangat Negatif" = (score < -5),
  "Negatif" = (score == -1 | score == -2 | score == -3 | score == -4),
  .method = "first",
  .default = NA
))
```

from post [can dplyr package be used for conditional mutating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating/33289639#33289639)

i tried `1 <= score && score <= 4` for between 1 to 4 (or -1 to -4 ) but it's just not working...