# How to count by group and find if at least one observation meets a criteria?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to summarise sales data grouping by city and adding a column where "1" means "the city has at least one store that sells more than 100" and "0" means "otherwise".

This is an approximation of what I'm trying:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data <- tibble(city = c("City 1","City 1","City 2","City 1"), 
                  store = c("mc donalds","starbucks","target","jp licks"), 
                  sales = c(300,200,3000,80),
                  sales_higher_than_100 = c(1,1,1,0))

my_data %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  summarise(has_stores_that_sell_more_than_100 = sum(sales_higher_than_100))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
    city has_stores_that_sell_more_than_100
   <chr>                              <dbl>
1 City 1                                  2
2 City 2                                  1
```

However, instead of summation I'd like to report a value of 1 for "City 1" like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    city has_stores_that_sell_more_than_100
   <chr>                              <dbl>
1 City 1                                  1
2 City 2                                  1
```

In other words, I wonder how to instruct dplyr to find if one or more of the rows of City N meet a condition instead of counting each of the rows that meet the condition for City N.

Comment: Maybe `max` instead of `sum`?

Comment: you can also try `summarise(as.numeric(any(sales>100)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ifelse` :

```
my_data %>%
  mutate(res = ifelse(sales>= 100), 1,
               ifelse(sales<100, 0, NA)))
```

Using if_else:

```
my_data %>%
      mutate(res = if_else(sales>= 100), 1,
                   if_else(sales<100, 0, NA_real_)))
```

Using `basic r`:
after you have final dataframe with the sales values dataframe,
`my_data$newcolumn<- my_data$sales[my_data$sales >= 100] <- 1`

Using `case_when`:

```
my_data %>%
  select(name:sales) %>%
  mutate(
    type = case_when(
      sales > 100 ~ "True",
      TRUE ~ "False"
    )
  )
```

See here : http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Using `derived factor`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mosaic)
#if salesvolume is the column that has number of sales 
my_data <- mutate(my_data, res= as.numeric(derivedFactor(
     "1" = (salesvolume >= 100)),
     "0" = (salesvolume < 100),
     .method = "first",
     .default = NA
     )))
```

see : [can dplyr package be used for conditional mutating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating)

Answer (score 2):

Could put a logical in there ">0" and then convert it to a numeric whereby TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0

```
my_data %>% 
group_by(city) %>% 
summarise(has_stores_that_sell_more_than_100 = as.numeric(sum(sales_higher_than_100)>0))
```

Comment: Or `as.integer`.