# Subtracting or adding to column value based on its value in R

Tags: r, row, addition, subtraction

I Have a dataframe named `mydata`. Here's a sample of the relevant column:

```
Accuracy.Percentage
100.00
127.00
60.00
175.00
52.00
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is the following: when the value of a row is < 100, I want change its value with `100 - mydata$Accuracy.Percentage`, when the value is > 100, I want to change its value with `mydata$Accuracy.Percentage - 100`. I have tried something like

```
result <- if(mydata$Accuracy.Percentage < 100) { 
  mutate(result$Accuracy.Percentage = 100 - result$Accuracy.Percentage) 
  } 
else mutate(result$Accuracy.Percentage = result$Accuracy.Percentage - 100)
```

But I can't seem to get it to work, although there probably is a simple way to accomplish this. Thanks in advance, I hope I have been clear enough and formulated my question in a understandable manner!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `ifelse`.

```
ifelse(
  mydata$Accuracy.Percentage < 100,
  100 - mydata$Accuracy.Percentage,
  mydata$Accuracy.Percentage - 100
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [abs()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/MathFun) will help you, but you need to remember the [ifelse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/ifelse) statement (`ifelse(test, true, false)`):

```
mutate(ifelse(
    mydata$Accuracy.Percentage < 100,
    result$Accuracy.Percentage=100-result$Accuracy.Percentage
    result$Accuracy.Percentage=result$Accuracy.Percentage-100
))
```

*Edited with @nadizan comment*

Comment: I would suggest you to call `mutate` once and use pipes before the `ifelse` statement, maybe also using `if_else` instead. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating

Comment: Whoops, I've used his ifelse. Very nice observation!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Like you mentioned, in the end abs() was all I needed!