# Conditional mutating with dplyr for multiple columns at the same time

Tags: r, dplyr

Conditional mutating in `dplyr` is "easy" (kind of) using `if_else()`:

[can dplyr package be used for conditional mutating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating)

However, suppose I want to `mutate` columns `x,y,z` at the same time, based on a logical condition C which depends on column `group`: also, the `mutat`ion happens only if C is `TRUE`, otherwise `x,y,z` stay the same. How can I do that? In base R, it's straightforward:

```
n <- 5 
k <- 10
my_labels <- LETTERS[1:5]

foobar <- data.frame(group = gl(n, k, labels = my_labels), x = runif(n*k), y=rnorm(n*k), z = rpois(n*k, 1), month_name = (rep(month.name[1:k], n)))

# mutate x, y, z, only if the condition on group is TRUE
foobar[foobar$group %in% c("B","E"), c("x", "y", "z")] <- NA
```

How do I achieve the same result with `dplyr` (if possible)?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `replace` within `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
foobar %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(x, y, z),
       funs(replace(., group %in% c("B", "E"), NA)))
```

---

If we want to use `if_else`

```
foobar %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(x, y, z),
      funs(if_else(group %in% c("B", "E"), NA_real_, as.numeric(.))))
```

Comment: interesting: is  `replace` a base R function'? I will have to read its help.

Comment: @DeltaIV  Yes, it is a base R function.  It is more convenient than `ifelse` or the dplyr::if_else (which does additional type check) as we need to only replace some values with a single value

Comment: cool! I suppose I can also wrap it in a function outside `funs`, right? I mean, the following should work: `replacer <- function(x) replace(x, group %in% c("B", "E"), NA)` and then `...mutate_at(vars(x, y, z), replacer) `. Correct?

Comment: @DeltaIV  Instead of having subset of functions, I would create a single function and do this i.e. `f1 <- function(dat, varS, grp) {dat %>% mutate_at(vars(varS), funs(replace(., !! rlang::sym(grp %in% c("B", "E"), NA)))}`

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr::across` available from dplyr 1.0.0 onward, you could do:

```
foobar %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x, y, z), 
         ~ if_else(group %in% c("B", "E"), NA_real_, as.numeric(.x))))
```