# Dplyr conditional select and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have working code which excludes columns based on a parameter and mutates certain columns based on other parameters. There is this SO question [Can dplyr package be used for conditional mutating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating) but it does not address conditional select

Is there a way to have pure dplyr code without the if statements?

Working R Code:

```
# Loading
diamonds_tbl <- diamonds
head(diamonds_tbl)

# parameters
initialColumnDrop <-  c('x','y','z')
forceCategoricalColumns <- c('carat','cut', 'color')
forceNumericalColumns <- c('')

# Main Code
if(length(which(colnames(diamonds_tbl) %in% initialColumnDrop))>=1){
    diamonds_tbl_clean <- diamonds_tbl %>%
    select(-one_of(initialColumnDrop))  #Drop specific columns in columnDrop
}

if(length(which(colnames(diamonds_tbl_clean) %in% forceCategoricalColumns))>=1){
    diamonds_tbl_clean <- diamonds_tbl_clean %>%
    mutate_at(forceCategoricalColumns,funs(as.character)) #Force columns to be categorical
}

if(length(which(colnames(diamonds_tbl_clean) %in% forceNumericalColumns))>=1){
    diamonds_tbl_clean <- diamonds_tbl_clean %>%
    mutate_at(forceNumericalColumns,funs(as.numeric)) #Force columns to be numeric
}
```

Comment: What would be the advantages of "pure dplyr"? dplyr is meant to help with transformation, but where you seem to be using the `if` statement for control flow which is very different and exactly what `if` statements are meant for.

Comment: 1> i am not after pure dplyr but want to check if  "If" statements are most efficient.  2> "If" statements are to protect against the parameters like"forceCategoricalColumns" being empty in which case the code would fail.

Comment: why the down voting? Down voting is fine but at least explain your rationale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the desire for a "pure dplyr" solution, but you can make any problem easier with helper functions. For example you could write a a function to run a transformation only if certain columns are found

```
run_if_cols_match <- function(data, cols, expr) {
  if (any(names(data) %in% cols)) {
    expr(data)
  } else {
    data
  }
}
```

Then you could use that in a pipe

```
diamonds_tbl_clean  <- diamonds_tbl %>% 
  run_if_cols_match(initialColumnDrop, 
        . %>% select(-one_of(initialColumnDrop))) %>% 
  run_if_cols_match(forceCategoricalColumns, 
        . %>% mutate_at(forceCategoricalColumns,funs(as.character))) %>% 
  run_if_cols_match(forceNumericalColumns, 
        . %>% mutate_at(forceNumericalColumns,funs(as.numeric)))
```

which would do the same thing as your code. Here just just conditionally run different anonymous pipes.