# Is there an R function for mutating rows given spesific criterias?

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have data [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS3tR.png).

I am trying to multiply a row given a specific Year and Name. I want to multiply the row by a value given it satisfies a given name and year requirement. For example `Year = 2006`, and `Name = ABG Sundal Collier Holding`. I find it hard to manipulate a row versus column that is easy to do changes in with `dplyr` package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I'm not trying to make a new variable (or row), only multiplying the existing row with a value.

Comment: in `data.table` the syntax is:  `dt[ rowfilter, column := new_value]`.

Comment: Are you looking for `ifelse`? Like `df %>% mutate(new_var = ifelse(Year == 2006 & Name == "ABG Sundal Collier Holding", 2 * old_value, old_value))`

Comment: Thank you! I think ifelse is what im looking for. But i have problems applying it on my data. I'm not trying to make a new row, just replacing the values in the existing row with the new values

Comment: Please include (some) data (`dput(mydata)` is best)  and show the code you have tried so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can dplyr package be used for conditional mutating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating)

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally replace the existing values in a row by using case_when or if_else:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Name = rep("ABG Sundal Collier Holding", 3), Year = c(2004, 2005, 2006), SomeValue = c(5, 10, 15))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(SomeValue = case_when(Name == "ABG Sundal Collier Holding" & Year == 2006 ~ SomeValue * 10, 
        TRUE ~ SomeValue))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(SomeValue = if_else(Name == "ABG Sundal Collier Holding" & Year == 2006, SomeValue * 10, SomeValue))
```