# I am trying to use the mutate function with conditions to create a new column from existing data

Tags: r, dplyr

Column 1

1 <=
 2 <=
 3 =
 4 <=
 5 =
 6 >
 7 <=
 8 =
 9 <=
10 =

Column 2

1 0.5
 2 0.5
 3 8
 4 0.5
 5 1
 6 32
 7 0.5
 8 1
 9 0.5
10 8

I need column 3.

I know this will not work in R, but this is what I want to get.

```
mutate(if(col1 = "<="){
  start <- 0
} else if(col1 = "="){
  start <- col2/2
} else if(col1 = ">"){
  start <- paste(col2)
})
```

Data:

```
structure(list(`col1` = c("<=", "<=", "=", "<=", "=", ">"
), col2 = c("0.5", "0.5", "8", "0.5", "1", "32")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `mutate(dataframe, col3 = case_when(col1 == "<=" ~ 0, col1 == "=" ~ col2/2, col1 == ">" ~ col2))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can dplyr package be used for conditional mutating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating)

Comment: This error appears: Problem with `mutate()` input `Col3`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `Col3` is `case_when(...)`.
Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-dplyr::mutate(...)
 2. \-dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
 3.   \-dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)
<parent: error/simpleError>
non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Could you please run the command dput(head(nameofyourdataframe)) and edit your question to include it

Comment: Thank you adjusted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With adjustment for your `dput`

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% mutate(start = case_when(
  col1 == "<=" ~ 0,
  col1 == "=" ~ as.numeric(col2) / 2,
  col1 == ">" ~ as.numeric(col2),
  TRUE ~ NA_real_
))


# A tibble: 6 x 3
  col1  col2  start
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 <=    0.5     0  
2 <=    0.5     0  
3 =     8       4  
4 <=    0.5     0  
5 =     1       0.5
6 >     32     32
```