# R: Create a new variable based on condition of two variables

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

How to create a condition in R, if the value of variable A is equal to the same value of B (without indication of the value of variables A and B), then create a new variable (C) with a new value.

For example, if the value of A == B, then a new variable C.

The ifelse function requires indicating the values of A and B.

Comment: Hello @Lena, can you create a minimal working example and show the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can dplyr package be used for conditional mutating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating)

Answer (score 0):

`A == B` creates a boolean, which you easily may coerce `as.integer`.

```
transform(dat, C=as.integer(A == B))
#   A B C
# 1 a b 0
# 2 a a 1
# 3 a b 0
# 4 a a 1
# 5 a b 0
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(A=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
                  B=c('b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'))
```