# How can I code multiple values in a single line?

Tags: r, dataframe, variable-assignment

I have a data frame with a series of indicator variables whose responses determine the scoring of a second set of variables. What I have works, but it seems clunky.

Here's an example of what I've written:

```
ET.data$Q1_RUR <-NA
ET.data$Q1_RUR[Q1==1] <- 0.18831667304039
ET.data$Q1_RUR[Q1==2] <- -0.118123181164265
```

I'd like to be able to condense it down to a single line, sort of like you can do in Stata:

```
recode Q1 (1=0.18831667304039)(2=-0.118123181164265)(else=.),generate(Q1_RUR)
```

Any ideas on how I could further refine? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating/24459900#24459900

Comment: Alternatively, `ET.data$Q1_RUR <- c(0.188, -0.111)[factor(Q1, levels=c(1,2))]`